# Using iCloud in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios5, icloud, ios-simulator

In my App, when I try to run code in the iOS Simulator:

```
NSURL *iCloudURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:@"2VHM28566N.com.eept.TestICloud"];
NSLog(@"IS ICloud : %@", [iCloudURL absoluteString]);
```

It shows that iCloudURL is nil.

Can we use iCloud without an iPhone device?

Comment: What is the @"2VHM28566N.com.eept.TestICloud"?  When I do this, I just pass nil as the argument.  Could you explain what this does please?

Comment: `2VHM28566N.com.eept.TestICloud` is the container ID for this person's specific app in question. If you look in your entitlements file or iCloud container list you will see a similar string in any of your apps that use iCloud. If you pass nil as the argument the system will use the first iCloud container it sees in the list.

Answer (score 25):

I tried to run my iCloud app today on the simulator and there is no option to enable iCloud in the simulator as far as I can see. I looked in settings, but no luck. So the answer would be no, you can't really test iCloud unless you test it on an actual device.

If anyone has a workaround, that would be fabulous. It's a bit tedious to always test your app on the device.

Comment: Since Xcode 5, the simulator has been supporting iCloud. Check the other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19710768/811830

Answer (score 19):

In Xcode 5:

> iOS Simulator now supports iCloud syncing of documents and KVS data
>   within an app, enabling apps to sync between devices using iCloud.
>   This feature is useful when testing to ensure that the app documents
>   and data are syncing properly across multiple devices.
>
> Note: With the app running in the iOS Simulator, sign in to an Apple
>   ID account using the Settings app. After signing in, use the “Trigger
>   iCloud sync” command in the Debug menu to tell the simulator to sync
>   with other devices.

Comment: And one more note "**iCloud simulator only works when simulating iOS 7.0 and later**"  - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW12

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but you can test iCloud by changing your deployment target to 'Device'. Plug your device in via USB and let the fun begin.

I would imagine that this is done for security reasons, and for a very good reason at that.

Because your device will have a mobile provisioning certificate which ties up with your iCloud 'bucket' as well as your App Bundle ID, it ensures that only you (your app and allowed devices) have access to your provisioned iCloud bucket.

If you could run it on the simulator without having all of these certificates and ID's in place, you could easily get a team ID from any other app which you download, slap together a project using that identifier and without a certificate marrying up developer, with iCloud bucket, you'd get full access to another App's bucket.

All I did to get around this was order a 5m USB extension so I can have my iPads, iPods and iPhones on the desk in front of me without having to crouch under a desk or sit in awkward positions whilst testing.

*edit* Just to add an slightly clearer answer as to what allthewayapps asks about the bundle ID.

```
2VHM28566N.com.eept.TestICloud
```

is made up of 3 parts in this case:

```
2VHM28566N  -  Being the TeamID which Apple assign you when you register as a developer

com.eept  -  Reverse domain notation of the App's related website i.e. Apple apps would have com.apple

TestICloud - The name of that app itself.
```

In short its:

```
teamid.com.yourdomain.appname
```

Hope this helps.